# PNG won't show in Bootstrap 4 navbar

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a png to the top of my navbar as a logo but for some reason it won't appear. All I get is the little photo icon which indicates the photo isn't displaying correctly. The photo is in resources/img/pdmalogo.png Thank you.

CODE:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="img/pdmalogo.png"></a>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Answer to my own question: I had the logo in resources/img/logo.png but I had to move the logo to public/img/logo.png. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You say the image is located in `resources/img/pdmalogo.png`, yet you reference `img/pdmalogo.png`. Assuming your page is a sibling of the `resources` folder, you're looking for:

```
<img src="resources/img/pdmalogo.png">
```

Comment: It’s actually a laravel app so it’s in App/Resources/img/pdmalogo.png so do I put the full path?

Comment: The path you need is relative to the file where it is referenced with `<img />`. So if that file is a sibling of the `App` folder, then yes.

Comment: I added the full path and still nothing.  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="resources/img/pdmalogo.png"></a> I still get the photo paper icon. Any ideas?